# React Redux Flowtype "property not found" in React element that gets properties from redux connect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, flowtype

I have a React component that uses the react-redux `connect` function (decorator) to set properties.  When referencing this component in JSX, flowtype complains "*property not found in... props of React element*"

```js
type SidebarCmpProps = {
  activeSidebarComponent: string,
  actions: { openCallMember: () => void }
}

@connect(
  (state) => {
    return { activeSidebarComponent: state.sidebar.activeSidebarComponent }
  },
  (dispatch) => ({ actions: bindActionCreators({ openCallMember }, dispatch) })
)
class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  props: SidebarCmpProps
  static propTypes = {
    actions: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    activeSidebarComponent: React.PropTypes.string
  }
}
```

The exact error is:

```
 65:         
             ^^^^^^^^^^^ React element `Sidebar`
 56:   props: SidebarCmpProps
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `actions`. Property not found in...
 65:         
             ^^^^^^^^^^^ props of React element `Sidebar`
```

To get around the error I had to change the properties to union types of `any` and add a `defaultProps`, which is less than ideal

```js
type SidebarCmpProps = {
  activeSidebarComponent: any | string,
  actions: any | { openCallMember: () => void }
}
class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps: SidebarCmpProps = {
    actions: null,
    activeSidebarComponent: null
  }
}
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Did you try giving `actions` a shape in `propTypes`?

Comment: Changing `actions` to a shape in `propTypes` doesn't prevent me from having to use the `any` union type to "solve" the error. I get the same error from the `activeSidebarComponent: string` prop as well (not pasted above for brevity)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are getting `property 'actions'. Property not found in` error because you are just setting `activeSidebarComponent` prop in `@connect` and actions is declared as required prop `actions: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired`.

So, you will have to set default value for `actions` prop or remove that restriction.

Comment: Yes, I know I could create dummy/no-op default values for some of these.  But that just creates a bunch of new and useless boilerplate since the default values will never be used as long as they are mapped in the `connect` function. I was hoping there's a way to configure flow to ignore this validation.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make both of the component props optional, you should define them like so:

```
type SidebarCmpProps = {
  activeSidebarComponent?: string,
  actions?: { openCallMember: () => void }
}
```

Also, I'm not sure if it's a good idea to provide both React's propTypes and a flowtype. That's duplication of logic, isn't it?

Comment: The issue is that I don't want it to be optional. Your suggestion will require me to have to check for null, which will be unnecessary because I know those properties will always be set by react-redux's `connect` function.  I'm effectively looking for a way to tell flow to ignore/skip this validation for particular components.